# Implementing Class Table Inheritance(CTI) across multiple database tables in Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, inheritance, doctrine-orm, mysql-error-1146

Need some help please?

I have 2 classes, a Parent class, say Person and a Child say Employee using Doctrine 2's class table inheritance mapping strategy. The classes' corresponding tables exist in separate database tables: Person table exists in database: dbOne and Employee table is in dbTwo.

The classes are like:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 * @Table(name="Person")
 */
class Person
{
```

and the child class

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="Employee")
 */
class Employee extends Person
{
```

The schema for the Employee table looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES **dbOne.Person**(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

There are two problems actually.

1. Since Doctrine maps one entity manager per database, if I call

$this->entityManager->flush();

On Person object, it flags an error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbOne.Employee' doesn't exist
```

The reverse is true if I call the entity manager (for dbTwo) to save an Employee object. 
The problem is absent when the tables are in the same database. How can I get around this issue please? Also, how can I retrieve the SQL query the entity manager uses during the flush() operation? It would be helpful to know what SQL is generated and used - like:

`$this->entityManager->getQuery();`//obviously this is just to explain what I mean

1. The second problem is getting Doctrine to insert the right value in the discr column of the database table: Person according to the @DiscriminatorMap details set. This works well when the value is Parent instance (i.e. Person) but not the child instance (i.e. Employee).  Thanks for helping out.

Comment: It appears that ORM technologies are limited in their ability to generate SQL queries that interrogate multiple databases in a single SQL statement (unit of work). This largely may be due to the fact that the entity manager is restricted to one database. This limitation may be responsible for this behavior.